# Does the Riemann zeta functional equation imply that if s is a zero of the Riemann zeta function then 1-s is also a zero?

Tags: riemann-zeta

The Functional Equation is as follows

[image: Riemann Zeta Functional Equation]

Does this equation imply that if s is a zero then 1-s is also a zero provided there are no poles that cancel out any zero?

Comment: Yes.$\text{}\text{}$

Comment: @Klaus what if s is a non trivial zero. Even then does the statement hold true? Can you provide a proof?

Comment: Actually only when $s$ is a non-trivial zero. The trivial zeros are caused by the $\sin$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You need to locate the zeros/poles of $\sin(\pi s/2)$ (easy) and $\Gamma(1-s)$ ($\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ indicates the poles, for the lack of zeros you'll need to prove $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi/\sin(\pi s)$) and to understand how the multiplication/division of **meromorphic** functions works.